# Applying derivative operation on Signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I've been given the formula below to apply to a signal. I'm not sure how to plug this into Matlab, can anyone explain?

y(n) =1/8[2x(n) + x(n − 1) − x(n − 3) − 2x(n − 4)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `x` is your input signal and `y` is your output, the expression you have can be regarded as an FIR filter. You can write the coefficients of `x` in a vector as `b = (1/8)*[2, 1, 0, -1, -2];` (the 0 in the middle is the coefficient of `x(n-2)`). Then you can apply it to your input data vector `x` using the `filter` function: `y = filter(b, 1, x);` (the 1 in the middle represents the coefficient of `y(n)`).

It may also be of interest to see the frequency response of the filter. To do so, you can use the `freqz` command: `freqz(b,1);`. See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/freqz.html) for more details, including how to calibrate the x-axis of the plot in Hz. Use of this function requires the Signal Processing Toolbox from the Mathworks.